# Reduce dimensions on a data set and its clusters' centroids

Tags: clustering, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am building a small application to calculate clusters from some input set (a n x p matrix). After I finish running the algorithm to get k clusters I also obtain the centroid of each cluster (a k x p matrix).

Then I need to plot the results, so I run Principal Components Analysis to map the input set into 2 dimensions (a n x 2 matrix).

My problem is that I want to plot the centroid of each cluster in the same graph. But I am not sure how to map the centroids matrix (k x p) into the projected k x 2 matrix.

I used to do this by adding the centroids as new entries to the input set before running the PCA algorithm, but I think this add some bias to the process.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the same transformation to the centroids that you applied to your data points.

Dimension reduction to 2D via PCA is just a matrix multiplication.

You may want to refresh your knowledge of PCA.

Comment: Yeah I thought that. But when I did it, the result was not correct. I am going to try it again then. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you also apply the same shift. PCA usually involves centering the data first.